# Can't figure out how to associate tables with php active record

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I must be missing something important but I can't sort this thing out
I would like to associate many addresses to a person so ... here we go with my settlement:
Is there anyone to help?

```
CREATE TABLE `testpersons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

CREATE TABLE `testaddresses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE `testassociate` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `testuser_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `testgroup_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Then I create my objects:

```
class Testperson extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'testpersons';
    static $has_many = array(
        array('testaddress',
            'through'=>'test_associate',
            'foreign_key'=>'testgroup_id',
            'primary_key'=>'testuser_id',
            'class_name'=>'Testaddress')
    );
}

class Testaddress extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'addresses';
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('testperson',
            'through'=>'test_associate',
            'foreign_key'=>'testuser_id',
            'primary_key'=>'testgroup_id')
        );
}
```

Then trying to get my result:
    $person = Testperson::find(2);
    echo var_dump ( $person);

Gives that:

```
object(Testperson)[16]
   public 'errors' => null
  private 'attributes' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
   array (size=2)
  'id' => int 2
  'name' => string 'tata' (length=4)
  private '__dirty' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
  array (size=0)
  empty
  private '__readonly' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false
private '__relationships' (ActiveRecord\Model) => 
 array (size=0)
   empty
private '__new_record' (ActiveRecord\Model) => boolean false
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my association?
Many thx

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is associate many `Address` to one `Person`, than your db structure is wrong and unnecessarily complex.
What you want is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `testpeople` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `testaddresses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `testperson_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Now your model would be like this:

```
class Testaddress extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('testperson')
    );
}

class Testperson extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'testpeople';

    static $has_many = array(
        array('testaddress')
    );
}
```

That should be enough.

However, when you want to use `through`, you should have also a model for the intermediate table with the respective relationship.
For example sake, I'll use your db structure.

```
class Testperson extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $table_name = 'testpeople';

    static $has_many = array(
        array('testassociate', 'foreign_key' => 'testuser_id'),
        array('testaddress', 'through' => 'testassociate', 'foreign_key' => 'testgroup_id')
    );
}

class Testassociate extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('testperson', 'foreign_key' => 'testuser_id'),
        array('testaddress', 'foreign_key' => 'testgroup_id'),
    );
}

class Testaddress extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $has_one = array(
        array('testassociate', 'foreign_key' => 'testgroup_id'),
        array('testaddress', 'through' => 'testassociate', 'foreign_key' => 'testuser_id'),
    );
}
```

Regarding the empty `__relathionships`, it's because that's a cache variable that will be populated when you request some relation, such as `$person->testaddresses`.